# Radioactivity counter

Tags: photoresistor

I am designing a Geiger counter which measures radioactivity. I am planning to this using the photoelectric effect.

The band gap of insulators is pretty big and only gamma particles are energetic enough to jump an electron from the valence band to the conduction band.

Where can I find a photo-resistor made of material with a band gap of 30+ eV? Can it be ordered online or is this a special case and it needs to be ordered from a factory?

Comment: Is there even such a thing? 4eV is considered high bandgap so 30eV is massive. Would such a material even be useful as a photoresistor with such a high bandgap? For gamma rays I guess.

Comment: Apparently 15eV counts as an insulator

Comment: As someone that works with x-rays commonly, you're effectively looking for a direct conversion material... Traditionally how it's done as you use a scintillator, a material that glows with visible-light when a gamma ray hits it. Then you use a typical photodiode to measure that visible light. unless you have a lot of money time and physics knowledge, I would suggest you stick with the typical Geiger Muller tube for a cheap geiger counter.

Comment: McCarter, you need to specify more what you mean by "measures radioactivity." A Geiger counter is, all by itself, a entire field of specialty devices. Some only respond to gamma (metal sealed cans, usually.) Some include mica windows of various thicknesses or other means to allow at least *some* beta to make it in. I think some even allow a fraction of high energy alphas. In any case, all you get is a "count" in most cases. Some measure the entire current curve and decay. NaI and CsI are two scintillation crystals usable with photometry sensors (usually PMTs) for more discerning measurements.

Comment: McCarter, so be very detailed about exactly what you want to achieve. One of my very first design projects was to design and build a Geiger counter. I wrote to a physicist who had designed the tube I wanted to use, who actually sold me a tube for $8 directly, and helped me understand more detail about a design. This was in the 1960's, though. So I used Bell Telephone 45 V (and 22.5 V) battery packs for power and a boost circuit regulated with a crafted string of NE-2 bulbs to maintain the voltage. Worked well as a toy device. It was not a measurement instrument. Still have my autunite sample!

Comment: This question might be better for physics also... Not EE

Comment: Try eBay, that's where I get my dark matter, and they have the best price on antineutrinos, so you never know.

Comment: Brian Drummond I will try it.

Comment: I would get an old scintillator crystal (lots on eBay) which is responsive in the range of energies of interest and a very sensitive photodetector to detect the generated photons. Classic way to do it is with a photomultiplier tube, although they're expensive and you need a high voltage supply. Look into silicon photomultipliers maybe - they are basically large SPAD arrays with very good dynamic range. They're cheap (tens of $ in singles) and don't need a particularly high bias voltage to operate (<100 V).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are apps (with Raspberry Pi and similar devices) for this. I'm not sure on their bad gap level, but I'd presume the very widely.

First Sensor provides some high quality photo-diodes for this purpose.

[image]

[first-sensor.com/cms/upload/datasheets/gamma-ray-detection.pdf](https://www.first-sensor.com/cms/upload/datasheets/gamma-ray-detection.pdf)

---

Aside, I don't think it's correct to say "Geiger counter" because it's not using a Geiger–Müller tube. "Rad detector" is more apt :)

Comment: Lol.Thank you...

Comment: 10 KeV is relatively low energy... Effectively what your chart shows is a photodiode that you still need to put a scintillating material on.